# Measuring avaliable free space on screen in Android

Tags: android, screen

In my app i have few views with hard-coded height in DPs. I want to know how can I measure the remaining available space in screen. I need this so I could set the height and width of the images in CoverFlow, which will take all remaining height. I think the height and width should be set individually to each device, depending on the parameters of its screen.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code: It works for me if you have any issue still than let men know

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();       
    int sWidth = display.getWidth();
    int sHieght = display.getHeight();
        }
```

than you can resize your image with the ratio of your screen size by using this method:

```
      private void resizeImage()
        {
        Bitmap bitmap; // Bitmap of your image

       int Width=swidth-usedWidth; // replace usedWidth with your occupied space by other widgets
     int Height=sHieght-usedHieght; 
     int h=bitmap.getHeight()*Width/bitmap.getWidth();  
     int w=bitmap.getWidth()*Height/bitmap.getHeight();                                 
     bitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,w, h, true);
        }
```